# EditText memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, leakcanary

I'm using Android 6.0. With the following layout LeakCanary finds memory leak:

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

      <ImageView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true"
          android:src="@drawable/background"/>

      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Simple hint"
            android:inputType="number|textNoSuggestions"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title_text"/>
      </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Without `EditText` memory leaks gone. Here is LeakCanary log:

```
D/LeakCanary: * com.testapp.MainActivity has leaked:
D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT static android.content.res.Resources.sPreloadedDrawables
D/LeakCanary: * references array android.util.LongSparseArray[].[0]
D/LeakCanary: * references android.util.LongSparseArray.mValues
D/LeakCanary: * references array java.lang.Object[].[2]
D/LeakCanary: * references android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable$InsetState.mDrawableState
D/LeakCanary: * references android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.mRes
D/LeakCanary: * references android.support.v7.widget.TintResources.mContext
D/LeakCanary: * leaks com.testapp.MainActivity instance
```

Has anybody the same problem? How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If that leak is correct, then it would be leaking in the library, it's something that Google would have to fix in the support library.

Comment: Yep, not only me have this problem. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202379